# Is cleanup necessary for a delegate BeginInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, delegates, .net-2.0

Do we need to call EndInvoke() and close the wait handle after calling a delegate BeginInvoke() even when we do not need to wait for the result?
Any resource leak if do not do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; you do always need to call `EndInvoke()`.
Otherwise, .Net will hold the result forever, in case you eventually do call `EndInvoke()`.

If you want a "fire and forget it" asynchronous invocation (or even if you don't), you should use the `Task` class, which is much nicer.

Comment: No Task class in .NET 2.0/3.5